# Como agregar peticion POST a RETROFIT en KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo para mostrar una serie de materiales para busqueda asiganado a un solo empleado mi aplicacion hasta el momento me muestra correctamente cada uno de los materiales pero estoy atorado en la parte de como poder crear la vista en la que se ingrese el numero de empleado para realizar la consulta de los materiales asignados a el.

Si me pudieran orientar de que manera deberia enviar la peticion post

Actualmente mi codigo esta asi

tengo una clase llamada `UserSession.kt`

```
class UserSession : AppCompatActivity() {

    var txtusern: EditText? = null
    var btnstart: Button? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_session)

        txtusern=findViewById(R.id.etUserName)
        btnstart=findViewById(R.id.btnStart)

        btnstart?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { 
            
        })


    }
}
```

Y asi tengo mi api

`EmployeeApi.kt`

```
interface EmployeeApi {

    @GET("getEmployees.php")
    suspend fun getQues():Response<MaterialListResponse>

}
```

`getEmployees.php`

```
<?php

include 'databaseConfig.php';

// $employee = $_POST['employee'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id_pickeo,employee, Nombre, planta, requisicion, material_number, qty_to_pick, zone_ma, rack_location, po_task_id from picking,workin,empleados 
                        where workin.employee= `$employee` and workin.employee=empleados.codigo_persona and left(rack_location,1) = workin.plant and date(date_register) = date(now()) 
                        and date(date_asign) = date(now()) order by picking.rack_location asc");

$stmt->execute();

//executing the query
$stmt->bind_result($id,$aso, $name, $planta, $requisicion, $material, $qty, $zone, $rack, $po);

$products = array();

//traversing through all the result
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['id_pickeo'] = $id;
    $temp['employee'] = $aso;
    $temp['Nombre'] = $name;
    $temp['planta'] = $planta;
    $temp['requisicion'] =$requisicion;
    $temp['material_number'] =$material;
    $temp['qty_to_pick'] =$qty;
    $temp['zone_ma'] = $zone;
    $temp['rack_location'] = $rack;
    $temp['po_task_id'] = $po;
    array_push($products, $temp);
}

echo json_encode($products);

?>
```

Como logro enviar desde mi clase `usersession` el numero de reloj del empleado al archivo `getEmployees.php`.